# Sobrepor imagem com uma DIV

Tags: css

Como faço para colocar uma DIV sobre uma imagem <'img'> ?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

HTML

```
<div id="main-banner">

<img src="images/wall.jpg" />

<div id="main-banner-content"></div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
#main-banner {
    padding: 0;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 330px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: blue
}
#main-banner-content {
    height: 250px;
    width: 700px;
    float: right;
    margin: 40px 60px;
    background: #555;
}
```

Comment: Pode explicar melhor como quer que a div se comporte? Explique melhor o contexto. Isso é simples, mas pode variar como se faz dependndo da utilização que quer dar e se o resto do HTML é fixo ou responsivo. Por exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/t0spre9g/

Comment: É fixo, seria num layout como esse:
http://s8.postimg.org/7ee88htlh/image.jpg

Comment: Ok, serve o jsFiddle que coloquei nos commentários em cima ^ ?

Comment: Sim, ele ficou por cima, mas a div ficou na esquerda saindo do bloco, tem alguma forma de colocar ela na direita sem precisar colocar valores gigantescos no top/left?

Answer (score 6):

Você pode inserir a imagem dentro de uma div com position relative e dentro desta div, uma outra div com position absolute, por exemplo:

```css
div.img{position: relative; width: 480px; height: 300px}
div.img > img{width:100%; height: 100%}
div.img > div{position: absolute; left: 50%; margin-left: -120px; top: 50%; margin-top: -75px; background-color: black; width:50%; height: 50%; color: #FFF;}
```

```html
<div class="img">
  <img src="http://www.hdwallpapers.in/walls/windows_xp_bliss-wide.jpg" />
  <div>DIV</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Veja algumas possibilidades abaixo de como fazer.

***Opção 1***

Utilizando uma `div` com uma imagem em `background`.

**Demo**

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%
}
.background {
  background: url(http://www.hdwallpapers.in/walls/windows_xp_bliss-wide.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.superior {
  width: 40%;
  height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #000;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="background">
  <div class="superior">DIV</div>
</div>
```

***Opção 2***

Colocamos uma `div` para controlar a imagem. Na imagem setamos sua posição como `absolute` e a `div` interna também, nesse caso não há necessidade de setar a `div` interna como `absolute` em ambos os casos irão funcionar.

**Demo - Position: Absolute**

```css
.control {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.control img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.superior {
  width: 40%;
  height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #000;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #fff;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="control">
  <img src="http://www.hdwallpapers.in/walls/windows_xp_bliss-wide.jpg" alt="" />
  <div class="superior">DIV</div>
</div>
```

**Demo - Position: relative**

```css
.control {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}
.control img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.superior {
  width: 40%;
  text-align: center;
  background: #000;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="control">
  <img src="http://www.hdwallpapers.in/walls/windows_xp_bliss-wide.jpg" alt="" />
  <div class="superior">DIV</div>
</div>
```

Um conselho é você utilizar a primeira opção, nesses casos utilize `background-size:cover` a imagem tende a se comportar melhor.

Comment: Obrigado, fico com a opção 2 porque a imagem será mudada dinamicamente.

Answer (score 0):

Uma solução que simplifica muito é colocar a imagem como pano de fundo de uma div, que por sua vez contêm outra.

Ou seja:

```css
#main-banner {
    width: 500px;
    height: 200px;
    background: url("http://wallpapercow.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/Google-GMail-Desktop-Wallpaper.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
}
#main-banner-content {
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
    background: #555;
    margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="main-banner">
    <div id="main-banner-content"></div>
</div>
```